# Using scrollTop to detect scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to log how much the user is scrolling a wrapper.

The following code does not work.
I would like to know what am I doing wrong and how to fix it. Thanks!

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content')
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  console.log(content.scrollTop)
})
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrapper is the one with the scroll not the content, so it is always going to be zero.

Comment: ok thanks, how much wrapper is being scrolled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `content.scrollTop`, but `wrapper.scrollTop`.

Answer (score 0):

To Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the vertical position of the scroll bar for every matched element.

`scrollTop()` : The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area. If the scroll bar is at the very top, or if the element is not scrollable, this number will be 0.

```js
$('#wrapper').scroll(function() {
  console.log($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```